# Fleet can't launch Docker registry container

Tags: docker, coreos, fleet

I'm brand-spanking-new to Docker and CoreOS. I have a VM running CoreOS as its host, and I'd like to simply get the [WordPress container](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) running on it (as a "*Hello, Docker/CoreOS!*"-type primer.

I found [this excellent article](https://coreos.com/docs/launching-containers/launching/fleet-example-deployment/) which led me to SSH into the CoreOS VM and try:

```
fleetctl submit https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/
```

But when I run this, I get:

> Error creating units: error retrieving Unit(wordpress.service) from Registry: Get http://domain-sock/fleet/v1/units/wordpress.service?alt=json: dial unix /var/run/fleet.sock: no such file or directory

Any ideas as to what I need to do to get the WordPress container running, so that I could got to some URL and actually use it?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `fleet` is not yet running.

You should probably read through [Running CoreOS](https://coreos.com/docs/) documentation appropriate to your platform.  For example, [this document](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/platforms/vagrant/) for Vagrant has information about how to configure fleet to start when CoreOS boots, using a "cloud-config" document that is interpreted by `cloud-init` when the system first boots.

You can start `fleetd` manually by running:

```
systemctl start fleet
```

You will also need to start `etcd`.  Again, the documentation (hopefully!) shows you how to do all of this.

Comment: Thanks @larsks (+1) - but Fleet is definitely running, as `fleetctl -version` produces `fleetctl version 0.10.2`. Thoughts?

Comment: `fleetctl -version` does not attempt to contact the fleet server.  I am sure that your problem is that `fleetd` is not yet running.

Comment: Thanks larks. 

I can confirm that this is because `fleet` wasn't running. Also, `etcd` needs to be run before too, just as `larsks` comment. 

If you don't start etcd, you will got error `Error retrieving list of units from repository: googleapi: Error 503: fleet server unable to communicate with etcd`.